# Generalizing Pearson's coefficient to determine properties of embedded manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, correlation

I have the following dilemma:

We know that for random vectors we have Pearson's coefficient of skewness. I  think you all agree that in some sense it measures the shape properties of   the distribution.

Now let's generalize this: we have a set of vectors (dependent or  independent). Could we generalize the Pearson's R in a way to determine some properties of the embedded manifold such as shape and dimension?

Comment: By embedded manifold, do you mean if the distribution is continuous with density $f(x)$, the set of points $(x, f(x))$ considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Hi there,I am not familiar  , why do you say (x,f(x)) considered as a subset of R2 is there any  theoretical    approach for saying that?

Comment: Could  you please elaborate more?

Comment: I'm just try to understand what you meant by embedded manifold.  I was suggesting this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function